# Pandas not working when deploying into Heroku

Tags: heroku, discord.py

My Heroku app uses the `pandas` module. I deployed it and put it into `requirements.txt` and no errors were raised. It does not work when deployed.

> To test this, I did the following

I added a panda dataframe that had no relevance into a sample command, and found out that the `ping` did not print in the console.

```py
if message.content == 's!ping':
        # Checking Latency
        df = pandas.read_html(requests.get('https://example.com').text)[2]
        ping =  str(round(bot.latency, 3))
        print(ping)
```

One last thing to not

> When i run my code on my computer the discord bot **it works**, but when I deploy it to heroku **it does not**

Thanks.